# python call abstract method implemented by child class, from parent class

Tags: python, abstract-methods

I'm trying to do like that.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__init_first()
        self.__init_second()

    def __init_first(self):
        #do something

    @abstractmethod
    def __init_second(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def __init_second(self):
        #do something    

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def __init_second(self):
        #do something2

b = B()
c = C()
```

However, it always invoke `NotImplementedError`.
How can I use child class' `__init_second` function in parent class?

I searched a lot, but no answer for my question.

Comment: I would guess this is due to name mangling and `__init_second` in `B` being an entirely different method than the one in `A`. Generally you should not overwrite private / `__...` methods.

Comment: omg that's the answer!! thx a lot... I didn't know function with __ prefix works different. I thought it is just a convention.. that's why I cannot find answer while googling. really really thank you luck2302!!